# multi binding in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, multibinding

I am trying to do multiple binding in wpf.
here is my code:

```
<CheckBox>

<CheckBox.IsChecked>
  <MultiBinding Converter="{View:MultiConvertorOr}">
   <Binding ElementName="txtbox1" Path="Text" Converter="{View:TextToBool}" Mode="TwoWay">
   <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}" Path="IsSelected" Mode="TwoWay">
 </MultiBinding>
</CheckBox.IsChecked>

</CheckBox>
```

My goal is when I enter text I want the checkbox to be checked (what happens) and the listBoxItem to be selected. (this part is not working).
I also want to keep the binding between the itemListBox and the checkBox (this also works).

Any Ideas how can I do what I want? maybe with event triggers or something like it?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Is any Binding errors?

Comment: You might also post the converter code.

Comment: there is no binding errors, the binding works. Accept when i want that after entering text both checkbox and listboxItem will be selected.

Comment: Where is the listbox item in your visual tree with respect to the checkbox ? You may need to refer to it by name in your binding. See the debug output from VS for binding errors.